# Is there a function which does grouping numbers (thousand)?

Tags: perl, module, numbers, grouping

Is there somewhere hidden in a (small) module a function, which does this for me:

```
my $var = 23654325432;
$var = reverse $var;
$var =~ s/\d{3}\K(?=\d+)/_/g;
$var = reverse $var;
```

I like [Number::Format](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Number%3a%3aFormat) but it didn't pass all tests on windows.

```
use Number::Format;
my $nf = new Number::Format( 
    -thousands_sep   => ',',
    -decimal_point   => '.',
);

my $formatted = $nf->format_number( 23142153 );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at [perl5i](http://search.cpan.org/~mschwern/perl5i-v2.9.1/lib/perl5i.pm).  It has `commify` and `group_digits` methods.

Comment: Yes I like perl5i. Unfortunately it is vast with multiple dependencies, but a good resource nevertheless.

Comment: @Borodin, indeed, that's why I included the FAQ version. Schwern did a great job with perl5i, but the FAQ version is 1) educational and can spur some insight into solving problems with Perl and 2) it's universal to those shops that have strict CPAN policies. It's kind of the way I have to reverse engineer my own crap so that I'm not putting a lot of my toolkit idioms on SO which require tendrils of code throughout my entire toolset.

Comment: That looks to heavy for me only for that little thing.

Comment: @sid_com: The answer was to address the OP question of "is there...a...module".  See Borodin's comment above.

Answer (score 4):

The fastest method is in the [`perlfaq`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq5.html#How-can-I-output-my-numbers-with-commas-added?) ( `perldoc -q commas` ):

```
sub commify {
    local $_ = shift;
    1 while s/^([-+]?\d+)(\d{3})/$1,$2/;
    return $_;
}
```

Of course, I just came up with a function that beats this one by ~70%.

```
use constant THOU_SEP => ',';
use English qw<@LAST_MATCH_START @LAST_MATCH_END>;
sub ss_commify { 
    my $s = shift;
    return $s unless $s =~ m/\d{4,}/;
    my ( $f, $p ) = ( $LAST_MATCH_START[0], $LAST_MATCH_END[0] );
    my $ts = THOU_SEP;
    # |-- That is, replace a *0-length* substring at $p with the 
    # v   thousand separator
    substr( $s, $p, 0, $ts ) while ( $p -= 3 ) > $f; 
    return $s;
}
```

And it works with whatever text you have in front or back. The FAQ version just works with text in back (admittedly a *numeric* value in Perl).

The idea is find what you want to work on with the regex *once* and then simply use Perl's elastic string implementation to do the perfunctory work. A substitution for each of these seems to be a bit more overhead than necessary.

Answer (score 3):

I use

```
$num =~ s/(\d) (?= (?:\d{3})+ \b )/$1,/gx;
```

which just adds a comma after every digit that is followed by a multiple of three digits.

If you'd like a function instead:

```
sub commify {
  (my $num = $_[0]) =~ s/(\d) (?= (?:\d{3})+ \b )/$1,/gx;
  $num;
}

print commify(10 ** $_), "\n" for 1 .. 14;
```

**OUTPUT**

```
10
100
1,000
10,000
100,000
1,000,000
10,000,000
100,000,000
1,000,000,000
10,000,000,000
100,000,000,000
1,000,000,000,000
10,000,000,000,000
100,000,000,000,000
```